# Sending a Confirmation Email in PHP

Tags: php, email, sendmail

I am quite new to PHP and am experimenting with an online ordering website in php. I have come across a problem when trying to send a confirmation email using a 'cc'.

Every time an order is processed, the order always sends to the 'CC' address specified as the '$from' and the sender (the from) is what is specified in the '$to' section. In the email confirmation received, it only displays the from section and the 'to' and 'cc' are empty as demonstrated below:

```
From: **$_SESSION['od_email']**
To: *This space is empty*
CC: orders@business.co.uk
```

Can anyone help to point out where I am going wrong? I have attached the code below.

```
//THIS IS CODE FOR THE EMAIL WHICH IS AUTOMATICALLY SENT TO THE CUSTOMER AND THE BUSINESS WHEN AN ORDER IS SUCCESSFULLY COMPLETED
//define the receiver of the email
$to = $_SESSION['od_email'];
//define the subject of the email
$subject = 'Order Confirmation | Ref No for Order: '.  $_SESSION['orderId']; 
//define the message to be sent. Each line should be separated with \n
$message = 'test';
//Who the message is from
$from = "orders@business.co.uk";
$cc = "orders@business.co.uk";
//define the headers we want passed. Note that they are separated with \r\n
$headers = "From:" . $from;
//bcc header going to the to go to the business as confirmation
$headers = "cc:" . $cc;
//send the email
$mail_sent = @mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers );
```

What I need for it to show is:

```
From: **orders@business.co.uk**
To: **$_SESSION['od_email'];**
CC: **orders@business.co.uk**
```

Thanks in advance for any help given

Comment: Be sure to validate your inputs so nobody can inject headers into them.

Comment: Do you get any exceptions or errors when you remove the @?

Comment: The @ from where, after the mail?

Answer (score 2):

When you're going to set the CC, you're overwriting what was in $headers.  Try:

```
$headers = "From:" . $from . "\r\n";
$headers.= "Cc:" . $cc;
```

And if that doesn't help, there's always PHP's documentation on [`mail`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php).

Comment: Ok, thanks for that, now it had corrected the from section. However, the 'TO' section which is supposed to go to the customer is still blank. I will try figure this out with the PHP documentation.

Comment: Are you sure you want $_SESSION['od_email']? Have you stored the email in a session. If you are submitting a form then you would normally use $_POST['od_email'] or $_GET['od_email']

Answer (score 2):

I would go all out with your headers and make sure you set everything you need to,

```
// To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

// Additional headers
$headers .= 'To: ' .$to. "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: ' .$from. "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Cc: '.$cc. "\r\n";
```

also, I believe mail() needs a valid email address, I do not know how you have the email set before `$_SESSION['od_email']` but if you are running a test and literally expecting `$_SESSION['od_email']` to come with it that wont work, it will see it as a not valid email and return false, thus returning nothing.  To further diagnose that problem tho we would need to know how `$_SESSION['od_email']` is setup

**EDIT**

Okay I am pretty sure the issue is caused how you are setting up `$_SESSION['od_email]'` based on your comment below.

Note: I am assuming your database is `$db`, but if not you need to change `$db` to the prober name

Let's try this and see how it works

```
// Get Data from the Database
$query = "SELECT `od_email` FROM `tbl_order`";
$result = $db->query($query);
while ($data = $db->fetch_array($result)) {

// Set Up the SESSION email
$_SESSION['od_email'] = $data['od_email'];

// Prepare the Email
$to = $_SESSION['od_email'];
$subject = 'Order Confirmation | Ref No for Order: '.  $_SESSION['orderId']; 
$message = 'test';
$from = "orders@business.co.uk";
$cc = "orders@business.co.uk";

// To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

// Additional headers
$headers .= 'To: ' .$to. "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: ' .$from. "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Cc: '.$cc. "\r\n";

// Send the email
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);

}
```

Comment: Ok, so before this section, i have the following code to set the email:
//Code to retreive customer email
 $query  = "SELECT od_email 
 FROM tbl_order";
  $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
    $data = mysql_fetch_assoc($result); 

//THIS IS THE EMAIL SENT TO THE CUSTOMER and the restaurant
//define the receiver of the email
$_SESSION['od_email'] = $data['od_email'];
$sendto = $_SESSION['od_email'];

I am not 100% sure if this is correct

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't he just add an @mail ? such as...

```
$mail_sent = @mail( $od_email, $subject, $message, $headers );
```

or

```
mail( $od_email, $subject, $message, $headers );
```

Replacing any variables.

Always worked for me.

Comment: Correct except he has not set it to `$od_email` he has set the email to `$_SESSION['od_email']` which is also `$to`, but like I said, we have no idea what or how `$_SESSION['od_email']` is being setup and without that knowledge we cannot figure out why it is not sending.

Comment: @ChrisJamesChampeau Even still, if the variable has already been set as `od_email`, then theoretically, it should send an e-mail to it too. Without seeing his entire code, it's hard to tell really where the problem is.